# How do I replace Windows with Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, windows

I've got an old Windows machine that I want to replace with Ubuntu. I dont want to have Windows on the machine any more. How do I make that happend?

Comment: What have you tried? Just run the installation, really. It will offer you the option.

Answer (score 1):

If it is an old machine, use better Xubuntu or Lubuntu, which are less demanding to system resources. If you like to use ubuntu, use maximum RAM (2-4 GB is ok). With less memory you can run ito the troubles and performance can be slow then.

Easy steps: download ISO, burn ISO, install. You can use official guidelines: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation

Answer (score 0):

**Before you begin, make sure you've got backups of any files you may need from the old Windows machine.**

Next, simply follow the official installation instructions:

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-long-term-support
- Ubuntu 13.04 http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest

The basic process involves:

1. downloading the version of Ubuntu you want to install (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
2. making a bootable USB, CD, or DVD
3. boot up the computer using the USB/CD/DVD you just made
4. follow the on-screen installation instructions. **one of the installation steps asks you about disk allocation/partitioning -- select the "replace my current operating system" option in step 4.**

Good luck, and enjoy Ubuntu!

*If you encounter difficulties during the installation, or afterward, please check back with AskUbuntu to see if a similar question has been asked, and if not, feel free to ask a new question here for more help*

Comment: Depending on the age of your laptop you may experience performance issues with the older hardware. That's why I included the link to installing 12.04 LTS which may be a better option for you than 13.04. Otherwise, @Dee is correct: you may want to consider Xubuntu or Lubuntu which are less intensive variants of the standard Ubuntu.